# A colloquial name for juice boxes

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What are the colloquial names for juice boxes like the one below of children's size?

> A juice box, also called a carton or popper, is a small container used to conveniently carry and consume drinks (most often juice). They are frequently made of paperboard with an aluminum foil lining, but variations exist. Juice boxes are most popular with children, although other uses include emergency drinking water and wine.  ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juicebox_%28container%29))

[image]

Comment: Juice boxes are more formally known as aseptic packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've only ever heard these called *juice boxes*. I was not aware of any other name for them. But you've actually answered your own question in your question, with the information from the wikipedia article you linked:

> A juice box, ***also called a carton or popper***, is a small container used to conveniently carry and consume drinks (most often juice).

I've never heard *carton* or *popper*, but those might be regional terms (or BrE?). I'd just stick with calling them *juice boxes*. But the answer is in the question!

Comment: I think carton is BrE. However I am no native speaker of any English variety. Britons are welcome to pitch in.

Comment: I've heard them called _juice cartons_ (surely you've heard [_milk carton_](http://nwamotherlode.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/school-milk.jpg), right?), but I agree that _juice boxes_ seems to be [winning out](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=juice+carton%2Cjuice+boxes&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). I wonder if a _popper_ differs from a carton because you "pop" the straw through the foil (as opposed to a traditional carton, which gets opened by [unfolding](http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/C60fHBLRhrc/hqdefault.jpg)).

Comment: learner, in England and the rest of the UK, they are normally known as packets. Sometimes, they are known as cartons.

Comment: @J.R. I'd understand *juice carton* just fine, but I hadn't heard anyone actually call them that :)  Even when they're not in box-shape (Capri Sun comes to mind as the most common other shape) I still hear *juice box*. Tristan's *packet* actually makes more sense for the non-box-shaped ones; maybe we should pick that up in the US! :)

Comment: I would agree that "juice boxes" is the best name. It is colloquial, from my perspective. I've never heard them called anything else.

As for Capri-Sun, I usually just call them "Capri-Suns".

Comment: A further UK voice: I never remember hearing "juice box" while growing up in England, except when they were referred to in American TV shows. "Juice carton" was the standard for me. As for "popper", no idea (only know it in relation to handheld fireworks containing confetti).

Answer (score 3):

"Popper" is an Australian term which I think comes from how when you're finished you can blow the carton up and jump on it to make a "pop" sound (although not too certain on this). I think however that this is a regional variation within Australia even as some people (esp. Victorians and Tasmanians) call it a "Juice box" and have no idea what Im talking about when I say Popper

Answer (score 1):

In British they’re cartons, just not necessarily juice cartons, rather cartons of juice. A bit long winded, but just how it is.

I’ve never heard of poppers in this context before, only as a substitute for the word ‘buttons’, usually by elder folks; though I do believe that ‘Juice Box’ is the American term for cartons of juice.

Comment: For the record - a popper is a press-stud/snap fastener, not a button.

Answer (score 1):

I've called it a "Tetra Pak" since I was a child. It seems this term is actually the name of the company that developed the technology, and the package itself is called a ["Tetra Brik"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetra_Brik).

Answer (score -1):

Juice box does not exist in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary. These containers are called cartons in British English.